# Unable to parse the csv file in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie to the ruby on rails platform and I was just trying out couple of example codes. 
I was trying to run this example http://goodbadtech.com/2009/05/13/ruby-on-rails-import-csv-data-into-database/
I followed all the instructions but I am getting this error

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CsvImportController):

Please help me to bash this error.

Here is my Routes.rb

```
Imports::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
 get "csv_imports/csv_view"
#map.resources :imports
#map.import_proc '/import/proc/:id', :controller => "imports", :action => "proc_csv"
  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

    resources :imports
    import_proc '/import/proc/:id', :controller => "csv_imports", :action => "pro_csv"
    end 

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'csv_imports#csv_view'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Comment: Rails is looking for a `CsvImportController`, but I suppose you called it CSVImportController. Rename it and your problem might go away.

Comment: @Wukerplank: Do u mean in routes.rb file?

Comment: No, I think this refers to the controller. Just look at the `app/controllers/csv_import_controller.rb` file. What's the name of the class?

Comment: @Wukerplank the name of the class is ImportController.The File name is imports_controller.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file, containing the class `CsvImportsController` should be named `csv_imports_controller`. I believe that is the error. In your routing, you should have

```
resources :csv_imports
```

[EDIT] On the other hand, if your controller is named `ImportsController`, placed in `imports_controller.rb`, then inside your routing, you should have

```
resources :imports
```

Rails automatically tries to tie things together based on the names. This is what makes things easy if you follow them correctly. So `resources :imports` will assume there is a controller called `ImportsController`, which can be found in `app/controllers/imports_controller.rb`. It is best practice to call the relevant model `Import`, to be found in `app/models/import.rb`.

Hope this helps.

(also note that the blog-post you mention is for Rails 2 and not Rails 3)

Comment: Rails 2 and Rails 3 does it make much difference?

Comment: In this case: the generators have changed (use `rails generator`), the routing has changed (syntax is now much leaner), and in rails 3 you use gems instead of plugins (while they still work).

Comment: :I followed the instructions which u suggested, now I am getting another error "/home/jeevan/csv/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Imports (NameError)"

Comment: Please show your routes file. Or check [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) or the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: hey I have posted routes.rb. please to check and reply thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Confusing: how is your controller called? Do you have both `CsvImportsController` and the `ImportsController`?

Comment: Nope I have only one controller thats CsvImportsController I renamed the ImportsController to CsvImportsController

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? Your controller is named `CsvImportsController`, it should be located in a file called `csv_imports_controller.rb`, and in your `routes.rb` you should write `resources :csv_imports`.